# How can I determine the type of a particular drive?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hardware, getdrivetype

I feel somewhat noob yet with this of getting the Information of Hardware of the CPU, so i come with this request: Hard Drive, CD/DVD/Bluray reader, Floppy and if it's possible USB.
I've been looking on MSDN [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28VS.85%29.aspx) but seems i'm bad at searching or i don't understand it. Any idea?

Comment: What information do you want to get? What type of drive a given drive is? Volume/partition size? Physical device info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you didn't understand about the documentation you linked to...

The sole argument accepted by the function is the root directory of the drive you want to get information about (including a trailing backslash). The function returns a value indicating which type of drive that is. A chart is shown that gives the possible return values and what each of them mean.

For example:

```
GetDriveType(_T("C:\\"))    // returns DRIVE_FIXED if C:\ is my hard drive
GetDriveType(_T("A:\\"))    // returns DRIVE_REMOVABLE if A:\ is my floppy drive
GetDriveType(_T("D:\\"))    // returns DRIVE_CDROM if D:\ is a CD-ROM drive
GetDriveType(_T("N:\\"))    // returns DRIVE_REMOTE if N:\ is a network drive
```

It also says that if you want to determine whether a drive is a USB-type drive, you need to call the [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551967.aspx) and specify the `SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY` property.

Comment: What .h (header) file is GetDrivePath? If it needs one.

Comment: @Kazuma: All that information is at the very bottom of each documentation page on MSDN. In this case, it says: "WinBase.h (include Windows.h)". That means it's defined in `WinBase.h`, but you're not supposed to include that yourself. You should already have `Windows.h` included, so you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Yes, but when for example i do GetDrivePath() i get "Error: The identifier "GetDrivePath" is not defined." But i have Windows.h

Comment: @Kazuma: Sorry, my bad. I typed `GetDrivePath` repeatedly instead of `GetDriveType`. I've corrected it.

Comment: GetDriveType is not 100 % accurate. For example when I plug in my phone, it attaches a volume as a read-only disk. And GetDriveType says it is CD-ROM. Well, in a sense it is right, it is read-only memory... but definitely not a CD.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine that a device is USB device, you can open its handle and send IOCTL queries using DeviceIoControl() to get bus type a device is connected to.

[EnumUsbDrivesLetters](http://banderlogi.blogspot.com/2011/06/enum-drive-letters-attached-for-usb.html) - the post is in Russian but it contains C++ source code, so the matter could be understood easily.

Cheers, Andriy

Comment: this appears to be a valid answer to the question, or at least somewhat helpful (even though you have posted it very late). Be careful posting links to your own blog though - nothing wrong with it, just don't forget to mention it, so that it isn't considered to be promotional spam.

Answer (score 1):

The only all-in-one API I know of for Windows with that information is [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx), but it's not terribly simple to use. On the other hand, many programs communicate with devices directly, using pass-through control codes, or I/O control codes like [SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566204.aspx).

(I don't know how [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) works, but I'm guessing it uses a combination of these methods to get the system info needed.)