# Loop though all Drives?

Tags: c++, windows, device

Well, i've been working on a HDD Information ([How can I determine the type of a particular drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026119/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-a-particular-drive) And well, everything works fine. But i don't know how to "check" or "loop" though all Drives (Hard Disks, USBs, CD/DVD/Bluray, Memory Card, etc) how do i loop though them? Since i don't want to do GetDeviceType for every letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could call [`GetLogicalDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will give you a bitmask of used/unused drives:

> Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a bitmask representing the currently available disk drives. Bit position 0 (the least-significant bit) is drive A, bit position 1 is drive B, bit position 2 is drive C, and so on.

So, if bit 0 has value 0, drive A is not used, if it has value 1, it is used. Similarly for the other drive letters.

however, to get drive information about a specific drive, `GetDeviceType()` is the right tool - is there any constraint preventing you from using it?

```
GetLogicalDrives()
loop through result:
   what is the bit value for the current drive?
    - 0: drive not used, continue
    - 1: drive in use, check what type it is, using GetDeviceType()
```

Comment: Hmp, got it except the "Is the drive used?" How i check that?

Comment: @Kazuma: Did you read the linked documentation? Or even the complete first sentence of my response? Apparently not. I have edited the relevant part from the documentation into the answer, to spare you (*le gasp*) one click.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry. I didn't sleep in a long time and my eyes are "failing".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`FindFirstVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364425%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [`FindNextVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364431%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`FindVolumeClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364433%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Here is a complete example from MSDN: [Displaying Volume Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975%28VS.85%29.aspx).